# Strange error when trying to compute cotangent

Tags: matlab

I'm new to MATLAB, and I'm trying to make sense of some scripts I have. In one, I have an expression for computing short-circuit impedance (within the context of other expressions):

```
Z=tan(2*p*f*d/vp)
```

That's fine and dandy, but when I want to change from tangent to the negative cotangent (for an open-circuit) like this:

```
Z=-1/tan(2*p*f*d/vp)
```

It gives me an error at that line as follows:

```
?? Error using ==> mldivide
Matrix dimensions must agree
```

Now, AFAIK none of the subexpressions in computing Z are matrices. What makes it more confusing is that if I change `1/tan` with `cot` then it works (independently of whether I add a `-` sign in front of it or not):

```
Z=-cot(2*p*f*d/vp)
```

Any ideas? I've done my googling on the `mldivide` error, but I just don't see how that applies to computing the cotangent as literally the inverse of the tangent.

Am I missing a MATLAB peculiarity here? Thanks.

### -- EDIT --

I think I should have included the entire source code (originally for calculating input impedance for a short-circuit line, and attempted a chance from `tan` to `-cot` for an open-circuit line)

```
close all; % close all opened graphs
figure;    % open new graph

% define distributed line parameters
L=209.410e-9;  % line inductance in H/m
C=119.510e-12; % line capacitance in F/m

vp=1/sqrt(L*C); % phase velocity
Z0=sqrt(L/C);   % characteristic line impedance

d=0.1;          % line length
N=5000;         % number of sampling points

f=1e9+3e9*(0:N)/N;  % set frequency range

%Z=tan(2*pi*f*d/vp); % short circuit impedance

Z= -1/tan(2*pi*f*d/vp); % open circuit impedance

plot(f/1e9,abs(Z0*Z));
title('Input impedance of a short-circuit transmission line');
xlabel('Frequency {\itf}, GHz');
ylabel('Input impedance |Z|, {\Omega}');
axis([1 4 0 500]);
% print -deps 'fig2_28.eps' % if uncommented -> saves a copy of plot in EPS format
```

Comment: Not very easy to get up-votes around here is it?!

Comment: The internet is a cruel mistress ;)

Comment: Good that you are sorted now. I don't understand Matlab syntax either!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess one of p, f, or d is a matrix, so `tan(2*p*f*d/vp)` will be a matrix as well. 1/matrix won't work because that is defined to be the inverse of a matrix multiplication, where you have restrictions to the dimensions of your matrices.

Try

```
Z=-1./tan(2*p*f*d/vp)
```

This is the element-wise division. (I assume that's what you want.)

Comment: That's what it was (I edited my original question to include the entire source code), it seems that f is a matrix (I'm still grappling with MATLAB syntax.) Using the element-wise division operator as you suggested does the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

That code works fine so long as `p`, `f`, `d` and `vp` are all scalar.  Therefore, one of your inputs *must* be non-scalar.

Comment: Yeah, it was my f input. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `/` sign is matrix division (i.e. multiplication by the inverse from the right), which needs same-sized arrays. Normally, all works well with scalars, but sometimes, the interpreter will cough so that you have to use `./`, i.e. element-wise division, instead.

Comment: The interpreter will only cough *if* any of the inputs are non-scalar.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: I've had this happen with scalars before (some older version of Matlab, though) for no obvious reasons. Element-wise division fixes it.

Comment: @Oli - it was my `f` parameter, which apparently is a matrix :/

Answer (score 1):

```
>> p = 0.1;
>> f = 0.2;
>> d = 0.01;
>> vp =0.2;
>> Z=-1/tan(2*p*f*d/vp)

Z =

 -499.9993
```

It would seem that you are passing a matrix as Matlab tells you.

Comment: Indeed, it was my f input that was throwing things off.